# Converting time on time series

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, posixct

I'm reading a csv file of precipitation time series, the problem is when the time is `00:00`.

```
head(C1)
            fecha precip
1      09/04/2012      0
2 09/04/2012 0:05      0
3 09/04/2012 0:10      0
4 09/04/2012 0:20      0
5 09/04/2012 0:25      0
6 09/04/2012 0:30      0
```

I'm trying to obtain a zoo object, but if I change time to POSIXct, or POSIXlt:

```
C1$fecha <- as.POSIXct(C1$fecha, format="%d/%m/%Y %k:%M")
```

I get NA on problematic dates.

```
head(C1)
                fecha precip
1                <NA>      0
2 2012-04-09 00:05:00      0
3 2012-04-09 00:10:00      0
4 2012-04-09 00:20:00      0
5 2012-04-09 00:25:00      0
6 2012-04-09 00:30:00      0
```

Any hint on this? Thanks

Comment: how are you reading the file?

Comment: I’m using read.csv because I have to do some transformations on the preocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to find the strings that are short, i.e. don't have time information.  Then concatenate `0:00` to each of these strings before converting to datetime objects:

Create sample data:

```
x <- c("09/04/2012", "09/04/2012 0:05", "09/04/2012 0:10", "09/04/2012 0:20", 
       "09/04/2012 0:25", "09/04/2012 0:30")
```

Use `nchar()` to identify elements that are only 10 characters in length. Then `paste()` `0:00` to these elements:

```
index <- sapply(x, nchar) == 10
x[index] <- paste0(x[index], " 0:00")

as.POSIXct(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %k:%M")

[1] "2012-04-09 00:00:00 BST" "2012-04-09 00:05:00 BST" "2012-04-09 00:10:00 BST"
[4] "2012-04-09 00:20:00 BST" "2012-04-09 00:25:00 BST" "2012-04-09 00:30:00 BST"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is your vector of dates and date/times then try this:

```
as.POSIXct(paste(x, "00:00"), format = "%m/%d/%Y %k:%M")
```